# Show that the homology groups of different projective resolutions of the same R-module are isomorphic to one another

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module

I am taking a course on commutative algebra, and we just defined the Tor functor using projective resolutions of a module. The definition we have is:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $\varepsilon:P_*\rightarrow M$, $\eta:Q_*\rightarrow M$, two projective resolutions of $M$. For all $R$-modules $N$, we may define the chain complexes $P_*\otimes N \rightarrow M\otimes N \rightarrow 0$ and $Q_*\otimes N \rightarrow M\otimes N \rightarrow 0$. We then define the functor Tor$_i^R(M,N)=H_i(P_*\otimes N)$, where $H_i(P_*\otimes N)$ denotes the i-th homology group of the chain complex $P_*\otimes N \rightarrow M\otimes N \rightarrow 0$. We have $H_i(P_*\otimes N)\cong H_i(Q_*\otimes N)$.

The claim is that this definition is independent of the projective resolution chosen. The proof is left as an exercise for us. I was able to show $H_0(P_*\otimes N)\cong M\otimes N\cong H_0(Q_*\otimes N)$, but couldn't show the rest. The hint is to use the horseshoe lemma to somehow construct an isomorphism between the homology groups, but I don't know where to start exactly. I would very much appreciate it, if someone could give me hints or lead me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: show that $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ are homotopic.

Comment: We didn't define homotopy, so I don't know how I can do that. Is there any other way perhaps?

Comment: This is quite standard, maybe you should just wait until your course progresses a bit more? Did you prove that any two projective resolutions of a module are homotopic? This is rather fundamental (and proofs are available in any book on homological algebra) so if they are not covering this in the course, I'd read it! For example, Weibel has this material.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't think our course actually covers much of homological algebra since I wasn't able to find anything on homotopy in our script. The next section we have is on localisation and Noetherian rings. I will read the section in the book you suggested, and make sure to ask about this in our tutorials!

Comment: But the hint asks for the horseshoe lemma, not homotopy. I'd be interested to see how it can be applied here.